# Iteration with pug

Tags: loops, iteration, pug

I have a question, how could I make one object be inside another and be displayed in pug?

```
    - 
    var list = [
            {
                "title": "- Course",
                "link": "./course/index.html",
                "listName":[
                  {
                   "name":"01 - HTML"
                  },
                  {
                   "name":"02 - CSS"
                  }
                ] 
            },

        ]


        

    ol  
        each val in list 
            li  
                p= val.title
                ul 
                    li 
                        a(href=val.link, target="_blank") 
                          span= val.listName

    each val in list
        p= val.listName.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just indent the second `each` loop under the first but use a different variable name.  It also helps a lot if you give the variables "real" names instead of just "value" or "item" or "list" when you have nested loops like this.

Docs for iteration are [here](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

```
ol  
  each course in list 
    li  
      p= course.title
        ul 
          each chapter in course.listName
            li 
              a(href= chapter.link, target="_blank") 
                span= chapter.name
```